# cuda::cub error calling a __host__ function from a __device__ functionis not allowed

Tags: cuda

I use cub::DeviceReduce::Sum to compute the summation of a vector, but it gave me the error :

```
error: calling a __host__ function("cub::DeviceReduce::Sum<double *, double *> ") from a __device__ function("dotcubdev") is not allowed
error: identifier "cub::DeviceReduce::Sum<double *, double *> " is undefined in device code
```

The code sample is as follows:

```
__device__ void sumcubdev(double* a, double *sum, int N)
{
    // Declare, allocate, and initialize device-accessible pointers 
     //for input and output
    // Determine temporary device storage requirements
    void     *d_temp_storage = NULL;
    size_t   temp_storage_bytes = 0;
     cub::DeviceReduce::Sum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, a, sum, N);
    // Allocate temporary storage
    cudaMalloc(&d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes);
    // Run sum-reduction
     cub::DeviceReduce::Sum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, a, sum, N);
}
```

The code can run successfully in the "main{}" body, but it can't work in the function.

Answer (score 3):

To use a cub device-wide function from device code, it is necessary to build your project to support CUDA dynamic parallelism.  In the [cub documentation](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_reduce.html), this is indicated here:

> Usage Considerations
>   Dynamic parallelism. DeviceReduce methods can be called within kernel code on devices in which CUDA dynamic parallelism is supported.

For example, you can compile the code you have shown with:

```
$ cat t1364.cu
#include <cub/cub.cuh>
__device__ void sumcubdev(double* a, double *sum, int N)
{
    // Declare, allocate, and initialize device-accessible pointers
     //for input and output
    // Determine temporary device storage requirements
    void     *d_temp_storage = NULL;
    size_t   temp_storage_bytes = 0;
     cub::DeviceReduce::Sum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, a, sum, N);
    // Allocate temporary storage
    cudaMalloc(&d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes);
    // Run sum-reduction
     cub::DeviceReduce::Sum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, a, sum, N);
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -dc t1364.cu
$
```

(CUDA 9.2, CUB 1.8.0)

This means CUB will be launching child kernels to get the work done.

This is not a complete tutorial on how to use CUDA Dynamic Parallelism (CDP).  The above is the compile command only and omits the link step.  There are many questions here on the `cuda` tag which discuss CDP, you can read about it in two [blog articles](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/introduction-cuda-dynamic-parallelism/) and the [programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-dynamic-parallelism), and there are CUDA [sample projects](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-print--cuda-dynamic-parallelism-) showing how to compile and use it.